# Can not create rails app because of path problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, terminal, path, console

When I try to create a new rails app this error fires in the console:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby2.5: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

anyway when I write this line it goes ok and create the app successfully.

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

What is causing this? how can I fix it the way it is not the need to write the line I mentioned. I am using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I can't help you with your current problem. But my recommendation is to get rid of RVM and let rbenv handle ruby. From my point of view things are sooo much easier. no more gemsets to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed RVM, but your terminal doesn't know where RVM is. What you did is the right way, you just told the terminal to load the RVM script. To avoid having to do it everytime you start the terminal run the following command.

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Whatever is written in there, get executed when a new terminal or tab is open.